# My keras neural network does not predict handwritten numbers

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, mnist

I trained a feedforward neural network in Keras module, but there are some problems with it. The problem is the incorrect prediction of images with self-written digits.

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
RESHAPED = 784
X_train = X_train.reshape(60000, RESHAPED)
X_test = X_test.reshape(10000, RESHAPED)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, NB_CLASSES)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, NB_CLASSES)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(N_HIDDEN, input_shape=(RESHAPED,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(DROPOUT))
model.add(Dense(N_HIDDEN))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(DROPOUT))
model.add(Dense(NB_CLASSES))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer=OPTIMIZER,
          metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
                batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=NB_EPOCH,
                verbose=VERBOSE, validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT)
score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=VERBOSE) 
//output
....
Epoch 20/20
48000/48000 [==============================] - 2s 49us/step - loss: 0.0713 - 
acc: 0.9795 - val_loss: 0.1004 - val_acc: 0.9782
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 52us/step
Test score: 0.09572517980986121 
Test accuracy: 0.9781
```

Next, I upload my image, of dimension 28x28, which was self-written, for example - 2, and executed this script:

```
img_array = imageio.imread('2.png', as_gray=True)
predictions=model.predict(img_array.reshape(1,784))
print (np.argmax(predictions))
//output for example 3, but I expect - 2
```

I tried other pictures with different numbers, which also gave wrong predictions. What is wrong? Model shows-Test accuracy: 0.9781. Help me please)))

Answer (score 0):

You are using the MNIST Dataset. This set was originally created for the american post office. You'll have to deal with [regional handwriting variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_handwriting_variation) so make sure you have written american numbers.

On the other hand errors are normal. Make a bigger set of handwritten digits and make some tests.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem of data mismatch , in order to have a prefect accuracy on your own images , you need to make some preprocessing before , if you noticed one thing in the mnist dataset all images are white in  black background , this is one of the modification you should make to your own image , for more information check this awesome medium article :

https://medium.com/@o.kroeger/tensorflow-mnist-and-your-own-handwritten-digits-4d1cd32bbab4

Comment: @AndreyGlazyrin  With pleasure ! hope that helps